# How to bypass "Press any key to continue..." in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, exe

I am writing a batch file to run an executable with list of filenames as inputs.
Looks something like this:

`for %%x in (%*) do ( path\to\exe %%x )`

each instance of this executable produces a "Press any key to continue..." prompt which makes this halt if I leave my computer. I'd like to have the batch file execute one at a time without pausing between iterations.

Comment: Try: `( for %%x in (%*) do ( path\to\exe %%x ) ) < NUL`

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I found this answer so hard to find.